# What is the purpose of the ".well-known"-folder?

Tags: http, log-files, directory

If've found a new error message in our log files and would like to know,  for what this `.well_known` folder is used for.

Which application/client would **need to access such a folder** and which application would **create files inside it**?

Here are some entries of the PHP error log of one of my domain. (I removed the date, IP and target domains.)

```
0000/00/00 00:00:00 [error] 851#0: *88611 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /.well-known/apple-app-site-association HTTP/1.1", host: "exampleA.com"
0000/00/00 00:00:00 [error] 850#0: *89749 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /.well-known/assetlinks.json HTTP/1.1", host: "exampleA.com"
0000/00/00 00:00:00 [error] 850#0: *89767 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /.well-known/assetlinks.json HTTP/1.1", host: "exampleB.com"
0000/00/00 00:00:00 [error] 853#0: *90120 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /.well-known/apple-app-site-association HTTP/1.1", host: "exampleB.com"
0000/00/00 00:00:00 [error] 853#0: *90622 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /.well-known/apple-app-site-association HTTP/1.1", host: "www.exampleB.com"
0000/00/00 00:00:00 [error] 853#0: *90926 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /.well-known/assetlinks.json HTTP/1.1", host: "www.exampleA.com"
0000/00/00 00:00:00 [error] 854#0: *91780 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /.well-known/apple-app-site-association HTTP/1.1", host: "exampleA.com"
```

First I thought that I could be the one who generated this, but at the times I wasn't accessing/working these domains. And these access requests comes from 3 of our domains. (with different web-applications)

---

> **INFO1**: It seems the IP is from the Googlebot (crawler) But why is it
> so important to access these files? (We don't have these files in the folders. I checked for hidden files in all domain root directories.)

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/create-statement) one creates [these](http://example.digitalassetlinks.org/.well-known/assetlinks.json).
Similar question also on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812135/requests-to-well-known-apple-app-site-association). Best of luck.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

That `/.well-known/` subdirectory is defined by [<del>RFC 5785</del>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5785) [RFC 8615](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8615)

> It is increasingly common for Web-based protocols to require the
> discovery of policy or other information about a host ("site-wide
> metadata") before making a request.  For example, the Robots
> Exclusion Protocol http://www.robotstxt.org/ specifies a way for
> automated processes to obtain permission to access resources;
> likewise, the Platform for Privacy Preferences [W3C.REC-P3P-20020416]
> tells user-agents how to discover privacy policy beforehand.
>
> While there are several ways to access per-resource metadata (e.g.,
> HTTP headers, WebDAV's PROPFIND [RFC4918]), the perceived overhead
> (either in terms of client-perceived latency and/or deployment
> difficulties) associated with them often precludes their use in these
> scenarios.
>
> When this happens, it is common to designate a *"well-known
> location"*    for such data, so that it can be easily located.
> However, this    approach has the drawback of risking collisions, both
> with other such    designated *"well-known locations"* and with
> pre-existing resources.
>
> To address this, this memo defines a path prefix in HTTP(S) URIs
> for    these *"well-known locations"*, `/.well-known/`.  Future
> specifications    that need to define a resource for such site-wide
> metadata can    register their use to avoid collisions and minimise
> impingement upon    sites' URI space.

The reason that you see access forbidden errors might be the result of a blanket block on requests for hidden files/folders (paths starting with a dot <kbd>.</kbd>).
In case you do have useful content in /.well-known, [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/755662/) may be of interest.

Locations within that directory are then used for specific purposes,

- `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` is for IOS [universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)
- `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` is an (Android) [Digital Asset Link](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started)

Both of which support a similar purpose, they allow the site operator to instruct a visitor to open the site in an associated app, rather than in the (mobile) browser.

- `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` is the location for the proposed [Automatic Certificate Management Environment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8555) standard as the location for HTTP Identifier Validation as used by Let's Encrypt.

IANA maintains a comprehensive list of assigned well-known locations on [www.iana.org/assignments/well-known-uris/well-known-uris.xhtml](https://www.iana.org/assignments/well-known-uris/well-known-uris.xhtml) and [a similar list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_/.well-known/_services_offered_by_webservers) also includes a few different URI's that are not officially assigned and registered by IANA.